# SkyDrive PRO Form based authentication

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am new to Sharepoint and this is my second time I am doing something on Sharepoint. I was assigned a task to research about SkyDrive Pro to find out the possibility of having form based authentication in SkyDrive Pro.

I searched but there is nothing available for the authentication of SkyDrive Pro on the internet. I have the following questions

1. Is this possible to have Form Based Authentication for SkyDrive Pro? I am looking for options (in SkyDrive Pro Desktop application) like *Settings > Change Authentication Method > Select Method > Username/Password.*
2. Any helpful links to understand the authentication mechanism of SkyDrive Pro.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps

[Skydrive Pro doesn't remember saved credentials (FBA)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b580fe98-c177-4d5e-b3fd-74097541af85/skydrive-pro-doesnt-remember-saved-credentials-fba-and-gives-script-error-on-login)

Comment: The link was not helpful. I have scene that link before . It is just a question.